# State Management in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

What will happen when we move from one state to other in Phaser i.e. Array, objects, images loaded in the previous state are flushed when we move to the next state? 
  Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! Unfortunately, the question you asked isn't the best type for SO, and will probably get closed. Take a look at https://www.joshmorony.com/phaser-fundamentals-using-states-in-phaser/ While specific to Phaser 2, the general idea is the same for Phaser 3, the implementation is just a little different.

Comment: You have to buy Interphase1 to understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

By default, all display objects that you added to the game world (sprites, texts, etc.) are removed when switching to a different state. All of your loaded assets remain in the cache and you can use them in your new state.
You can change this behavior when you call start method on State manager.

```
game.state.start("nextState", true, true);
```

The second parameter specifies whether game objects should be cleared.
The third parameter says whether game cache should be cleared.